# ReactJS: HighLight background with variable random value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am displaying a table that gets data from the data.json file. I built the arrow function getColor to consider the color for the values ​​of columns d, e according to the conditions. Top 10 rows I need to change random data every 3s for columns d and e.
I want when the value in the cell changes, the color also changes according to the condition of the arrow function getColor and will highlight the cell with that changed value in 1s with two backgrouds corresponding to 2 different colors.
I'm not sure how to highlight background the cells that have changed values

below is what i did. You can also watch it at https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-perlman-qoi4wp?file=/src/App.js

the `App.js` file looks like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import data from './datafile/data.json';
import './styles.css'
export default function App() {

    const getColor = (a, b, c, value) =>{
      if(value > a && value < b){
          return "green";
      }else if(value > c && value < a){
          return "red"
      }
    }

    let ListData = data.list;
    let get10Data = ListData.slice(0, 10)

    const [list, setData] = useState(get10Data);
    const randomValue = (min, max) => {
        let value = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
        return value;
    }
    const ChangeData = () => {
      get10Data.slice().map((info) => {
        if (info.a && info.b &&
          info.c && info.d && info.e !== undefined) {
          randomValue(info.b, info.c)
          return (
            setData(get10Data.slice(0, 5)),
            info.d = randomValue(info.b, info.c),
            info.e = randomValue(info.b, info.c)
            )
        }else {
            return ''
        }
      })
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(ChangeData, 3000)
    }, [])  
    
    const Reacords = data.list.map(info => {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{info.name}</td>
                <td>{info.a}</td>
                <td>{info.b}</td>
                <td>{info.c}</td>
                <td className={getColor(info.a, info.b, info.c, info.d)}>{info.d}</td>
                <td className={getColor(info.a, info.b, info.c, info.e)}>{info.e}</td>
            </tr>
        )
    })

    return (
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>a</th>
                        <th>b</th>
                        <th>c</th>
                        <th>d</th>
                        <th>e</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {Reacords}
                </tbody>
            </table>

    );
}
```

the data.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "a": "ok",
  "list": [
      {
          "name": "A",
          "a": 50,
          "b": 90,
          "c": 30,
          "d": 40,
          "e": 85
      },
      {
          "name": "B",
          "a": 63,
          "b": 110,
          "c": 40,
          "d": 87,
          "e": 85
      },
      {
          "name": "C",
          "a": 48,
          "b": 85,
          "c": 25,
          "d": 30,
          "e": 43
      },
      {
        "name": "D",
        "a": 45,
        "b": 90,
        "c": 30,
        "d": 40,
        "e": 85
    },
    {
        "name": "E",
        "a": 63,
        "b": 110,
        "c": 40,
        "d": 87,
        "e": 85
    },
    {
        "name": "F",
        "a": 48,
        "b": 85,
        "c": 25,
        "d": 30,
        "e": 43
    },
    {
          "name": "G",
          "a": 50,
          "b": 90,
          "c": 30,
          "d": 40,
          "e": 85
      },
      {
          "name": "H",
          "a": 63,
          "b": 110,
          "c": 40,
          "d": 87,
          "e": 85
      },
      {
          "name": "I",
          "a": 48,
          "b": 85,
          "c": 25,
          "d": 30,
          "e": 43
      },
      {
        "name": "K",
        "a": 50,
        "b": 90,
        "c": 30,
        "d": 40,
        "e": 85
    },
    {
        "name": "L",
        "a": 63,
        "b": 110,
        "c": 40,
        "d": 87,
        "e": 85
    },
    {
        "name": "M",
        "a": 48,
        "b": 85,
        "c": 25,
        "d": 30,
        "e": 43
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope you can help. Please show an example of how it is done. random value generation part if anyone have another way can let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using `keyframes` to achieve the background color change with animation within 2 seconds (the 1st second to turn green/red, the 2nd second to turn back to the white background)

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
table {
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 90%;
}
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

@keyframes green-background-fade {
  50% {
    background: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.3);
  }
  100% {
    background: #fff;
  }
}

@keyframes red-background-fade {
  50% {
    background: rgba(128, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
  100% {
    background: #fff;
  }
}

.background-green {
  animation: green-background-fade 2s forwards;
}
.background-red {
  animation: red-background-fade 2s forwards;
}

.green {
  color: green;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

You also need to have `useEffect` with `setTimeout` to reset animation

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import data from "./datafile/data.json";
import "./styles.css";

const Row = ({ info, mainInfo }) => {
  const [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = useState("");
  const [textColor, setTextColor] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const color = getColor(info.a, info.b, info.c, mainInfo);
    setBackgroundColor(`background-${color}`);
    setTextColor(color);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setBackgroundColor("");
    }, 2000);
  }, [mainInfo]);

  const getColor = useCallback((a, b, c, value) => {
    if (value > a && value < b) {
      return "green";
    } else if (value > c && value < a) {
      return "red";
    }
  }, []);

  return <td className={[backgroundColor, textColor].join(" ")}>{mainInfo}</td>;
};

const Record = ({ info }) => {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{info.name}</td>
      <td>{info.a}</td>
      <td>{info.b}</td>
      <td>{info.c}</td>
      <Row info={info} mainInfo={info.d} />
      <Row info={info} mainInfo={info.e} />
    </tr>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  let ListData = data.list;
  let get10Data = ListData.slice(0, 10);

  const [list, setData] = useState(ListData);
  const randomValue = (min, max) => {
    let value = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    // value = parseFloat(value / 1000).toFixed(2) * 1000;
    return value;
  };
  const ChangeData = () => {
    get10Data.slice().map((info) => {
      if (info.a && info.b && info.c && info.d && info.e !== undefined) {
        randomValue(info.b, info.c);
        return (
          setData(get10Data.slice(0, 5)),
          (info.d = randomValue(info.b, info.c)),
          (info.e = randomValue(info.b, info.c))
        );
      } else {
        return "";
      }
    });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(ChangeData, 3000);
  }, []);

  const Records = data.list.map((info, index) => (
    <Record key={info.name + index} info={info} />
  ));

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>a</th>
          <th>b</th>
          <th>c</th>
          <th>d</th>
          <th>e</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>{Records}</tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

The full code is in [this sanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-bartik-j2qhdi?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't seem right. Because many data cells change, but the background remains the same

Comment: @denn it's changed but the color stays green/red which compares with the previous values. For example, green to green does not apply animation, but now I understood what you want, let me modify it

Comment: You can check the sandbox here again https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-bartik-j2qhdi?file=/src/styles.css:0-663 @denn